# spring boot startup error in pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a spring boot project in `Eclipse Oxygen` with STS with `java 8`.
I am getting error in pom at  attribute.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Below Error showing in eclipse on parent attribute in pom as

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle `configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)`

> CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo not present
>
> CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-testCompile: TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo not present

How can i fix above issue and run my project.
please guide.

Pom as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bootexmp</groupId>
    <artifactId>springBootExampl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springBootExampl</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
    
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build 
          itself. -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.8,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
         <!-- <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <version>1.8</version>
 -->          <!--   <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>CopyPropertyFiles</id>
                  <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <target>
                        <copy todir="${basedir}/src/main/resources" overwrite="true">
                           <fileset id="envpropfiles" dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/properties">
                              <include name="${env}-*.properties" />
                           </fileset> -->
                          <!--  <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)-(.*\.properties)" to="]  -->
                       <!--  </copy>
                     </target>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin> -->
        <!--  </plugins>
        <plugins> -->
        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e 
       settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
              <!--  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                               <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.5,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action> 
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <goals>
          <goal>list</goal>
        </goals>
        <versionRange>[0.0,)</versionRange>
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
      <action>
        <ignore />
      </action>
    </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>  -->
            
            
        </plugins>
        
      
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: You should post full content of file `pom.xml`

Comment: Did you create the project manually? I vaguely remember getting that when trying to do so without either using STS starter or importing Maven project instead. Anyway, run a `mvn clean install` where you pom is located and see if it runs properly

Comment: use spring initializr to help you create the project you need, with all poms and dependency versions working out of the box - https://start.spring.io/

Comment: I have post full pom , also when i am running mvn clean install , i am getting below error. [WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo not present